# Set Date and Timestamp property value in Java

Tags: java, date, timestamp, db2

I have class looking like this

```
class SomeClass {
  Date date;
  Timestamp timestamp;
}
```

What is the value of Date and Timestamp when I want to set property values like this:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

someClass.setDate(what value goes here?);
someClass.setTimestamp(what value goes here?)
```

I have to insert those values in DB2 which has columns with types Date and Timestamp

Comment: I strongly recommend that in Java you use neither of the two `Date` classes nor `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` for a DB2 date and `LocalDateTime` for a DB2 timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the datatype DB2 mapping with Java here

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=jsri-data-types-that-map-database-data-types-in-java-applications

```
java.sql.Date       DATE
java.sql.Time       TIME
java.sql.Timestamp  TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP(p), TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, 
                    TIMESTAMP(p) WITH TIME ZONE15,1
```

Java code

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Date dt = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    
    System.err.println("current date "+dt);
    System.err.println("current timestamps "+ts);
}

}
```

The output :

```
current date 2022-05-25
current timestamps 2022-05-25 11:45:12.858
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing the same type of objects in the setter methods.

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

someClass.setDate(new Date()); //
someClass.setTimestamp(new TimeStamp(LONG VALUE));
```